# awk loop printing wrong number of times

Tags: bash, awk, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a file like this (space tab):

```
Agent 299301 1
Person 259672 2
Place 208239 3
Location 208239 4
PopulatedPlace 156701 5
Region 153246 6
AdministrativeRegion 153246 7
Work 96536 8
Agent 299301 1
Person 259672 2
```

I want to return a different number for each row as many times as it appears in the second column

For example:
first, return number `1` 299301 times, then return `2` 259672 times, then return `3` 208239 times

For that I am using this awk command:

```
cat file | awk -F ' ' '{for (i=1; i<=$2; i++) print NR}'  > output
```

It seems to work well with small numbers on second column but in this file sample, I don't know why is returning each number (`1` in this case) the incorrect number of times:

It's returning number `1` **558973** times instead of **299301** times

But it returns the correct number in the rest of lines of the file (numbers `2, 3, 4...`)

And if I add more lines to the file, it also returns the wrong number of times with numbers `2, 3, 4` until number `9`, but then it also works well with numbers `10, 11, 12, 13...`

So I don't know why is this happening, hope you can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you checking how many times a given number appears in the output?

Comment: It works fine for me. How are you checking the output? I used `uniq -c output`. If it's relevant, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. It'd help to make the question title more descriptive, like for example "Why is AWK repeating the wrong number of times?" You can [edit].

Comment: Note that 1 is output 299301 times because of line 1, but then again because of line 9.

Comment: @choroba Not really, what is printed is not `$3` but `NR`... But your remark is interesting anyway.

Comment: It looks like the significance of 558973 is that it's 299301+259672. IDK why though.

Comment: I wonder if OP didn't just copy & paste but re-typed code and put in `NR` here when the real code uses `$3`.

Comment: Or maybe the original had `$NF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not your script that's wrong, it's how you're trying to validate it's output. You're piping the output to `grep '1' | wc -l` or similar and so are counting the number of `1`s (`299301`) + the number of `10`s (`259672`) and so getting the total `558973`.

```
$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=$2; i++) print NR}' file | grep '1' | wc -l
558973

$ awk '{for (i=1; i<=$2; i++) print NR}' file | grep '^1$' | wc -l
299301
```

By the way, `cat file` and `-F ' '` aren't doing any real harm but they also do nothing useful in this case, just use `awk '{for (i=1; i<=$2; i++) print NR}' file` instead as I did above.

Answer (score 0):

When fed the input presented in the question, the program presented in the question outputs '1' exactly 299301 times for me, as you expected.  I am inclined to suppose that @choroba's comment on the question is indicative of the nature of a *different* program with which you observed instead 558973 lines of '1'.  That is, the one in this, or something substantially equivalent:

```
cat file | awk -F ' ' '{for (i=1; i<=$2; i++) print $3}'  > output
```

The difference is that one prints `NR`, the input line number, whereas the other prints `$3`, the third field read from the input line.